# Jekyll buid fails using grunt-responsive-images

Tags: jekyll

HI this is the terminal output when I run jekyll build

```
    Configuration file: /Users/makingthings/Dropbox/Sites/jekyll-uh/_config.yml
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- jekyll-responsive_image (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:29:in `block in require_gems'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:26:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:26:in `require_gems'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:19:in `conscientious_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:79:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:41:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:29:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:29:in `process'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `call'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/bin/jekyll:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

Possibly conflicting ruby environments?

Answer (score 0):

Not so familiar with ruby but I got this working with config like this:

```
gems: [jekyll/responsive_image]
```